# Close a batch window only by typing "exit"?? disable the close "X" button on the top right of batch window

Tags: batch-file

I run a batch file which carries out some task for hours. BY mistake users happen to close the terminal window in which the batch file is executing by pressing the top right "X" close button.

I want to disable it and want to close the batch file window only by typing "exit" inside the window..is this possible?

Comment: I beliebe this is not possible by pure batch scripting, but you could use something else with capabilities to control windows and their appearances. Anyway, people could still use the Task Manager to terminate the console...

Comment: @aschipfl right. But I don't think, Task Manager is an issue here. Hard to do it "by mistake". This is not about intentionally killing.

Comment: Yes, @Stephan, I totally agree. I just wanted to point out this way of closing the running task...

Answer (score -1):

This can't be done using only one batch file. But there might be a really dirty way for this. You will need three batch files:

EDIT: Here is the solution. Put these three files into the same folder.

controller.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE CONTROLLER
IF NOT EXIST hiddenrunner.vbs (
    echo CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^).Run Wscript.Arguments^(0^), 0, False>hiddenrunner.vbs
)
tasklist /V|findstr "MONITOR"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 hiddenrunner.vbs monitor.bat
:INPUTLOOP
CLS
SET /P input=Type 'exit' to exit:
IF /i NOT %input%==exit GOTO INPUTLOOP
ECHO ok, exiting
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Administrator:  WORK" /T
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Administrator:  MONITOR" /T
ping localhost -n 2
del /Q hiddenrunner.vbs
```

monitor.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
TITLE MONITOR
hiddenrunner.vbs work.bat
:LOOP
tasklist /V|findstr "CONTROLLER"
IF !errorlevel!==1 START controller.bat
ping localhost -n 2
GOTO LOOP
```

work.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
title WORK
ping -t localhost
```

In your case, the work-file will be your original batch you want to execute. You'll have to adjust the window titles (like `TITLE CONTROLLER` and `WindowTitle eq Administrator:  WORK`) to fit your setup. However, this works for me. If the user closes the input console, it is being restarted after one second. All processes are being terminated after the user inputs `exit` in the input console.

Comment: `START /?` - `B           Start application without creating a new window.` There is no mention whatsoever about making anything run in the background!

Comment: @Compo This is correct but by adding `>nul 2>&1` you can suppress the output and you can terminate the spawned process separately without closing the first console. Not sure if this will work, if not, `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run some_batch.bat, 0, False` might help...

Comment: Your points 1., 2. and 3. are either incorrect or not explained well at all. Why speak of three batch files, _matching the batch-file tag_, but then provide a VB code snippet.

Comment: I'd like to try it without VBScript but if there is no other way, I'd try it using VBScript which can be called from a batch file. It seems hard or even impossible to solve the problem with pure batch. So do you want me to tell him that I won't offer him a possible solution until he adds a VBScript tag? What's wrong with you? By the way, do you have something useful to say or are you just nagging around?

Comment: No, provide a solution using VBScript, by way of a batch file, _the solution should use a batch file to either write, invoke or call the alternative scripting language._

Comment: OK, so you ARE just nagging around. /ignore

Comment: I thought I was pretty darn good with batch files, but from what you have actually posted I cannot see how it is done. If I cannot understand or see a solution then I'm doubting that the OP can either. You have stated that there may be a dirty way of doing it with three batch files, but have shown no batch files to back up that answer, just a piece of VBScript.

Comment: @Compo I've intended to wait until Abhi confirms that he wants this solution but now I did it just to show that it can be done.

Comment: That's a lot better @MichaelS, just a quick question and a couple of observations…Your WindowTitle, appears to be prepended with `Administrator: `, does that mean MONITOR and WORK are being `Run as administrator`. This information may be crucial; if what you've posted isn't running as Administrator by default or instruction, there will never be a matching WindowTitle to kill. _As a side note, in controller.bat you only need to escape the closing parentheses when echoing to the vbs, `%input%==exit` should really be `"%input%"=="exit"` and the `/Q` option isn't required for the `del` command._

Comment: 1st: "You'll have to adjust the window titles (like TITLE CONTROLLER and WindowTitle eq Administrator:  WORK) to fit your setup." 2nd: This is just a piece of code I've hacked in some minutes. Your only help was...well...nothing. Maybe you should answer the question next time instead of being a big smartass.